# UI changes on background thread due to NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification

Tags: ios, uikit, nsuserdefaults, nsnotificationcenter

I am debugging an issue that occasionally causes my app to crash with a `WebTryThreadLock` message in the crash report. It looks like the app is crashing because the `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` is being sent and received on a background thread. I make UI changes when the notification is received and understand that making UI changes on a background thread is highly advised against.

If `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` is sometimes (if not always) sent on a background thread, what is the best way to handle this? Something like the following seems excessive but potentially necessary.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(userDefaultsDidChange)
 name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
 object:nil];

- (void)userDefaultsDidChange {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUIWithNewUserDefaults)
                           withObject:nil
                        waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)updateUIWithNewUserDefaults {
    // Update UI
}
```

Comment: that is exactly the way to go about it. As you noted UIKit is not thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should send a message to the UI thread's dispatch queue and do your UI modifications from there.

Like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // your code here
});
```

See [Apple's Grand Central Dispatch documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

---  Dave

Comment: dispatch_get_global_queue() returns a concurrent queue of the given priority, not the main queue. You use dispatch_get_main_queue() to get the main queue, which is a serial queue.

Comment: Yep, either this or the selector-based approach I suggested in the original question are both suitable.