# Update MBProgressHUD while background process is running

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, grand-central-dispatch, mbprogresshud

I present in @interface ZxBancaD : UITableViewController a MBProgressHUD, every time a modal view is closed

```
- (void) disparaMa:(NSNotification *)notification {
   hudX                 = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.splitViewController.view animated:YES];
   hudX.delegate        = self;
   hudX.mode            = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
   hudX.labelText       = @"Pago Minimo...";
   hudX.dimBackground   = YES;
   [hudX showWhileExecuting:@selector(actEtiqueta) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^ (void) {
    [self miniAutomatico];
   });
}
```

I use this method to update my hudX

```
- (void) actEtiqueta {
   xP                       = 0.0f;
   while (xP < 1) {
     xT                     = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kVueltas];
     xP                     = ((double)xT)/24;
     hudX.detailsLabelText  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vuelta%i", xT];
     hudX.progress          = xP;
     NSLog(@"AxTiempoB.actEtiqueta.progress %f | xP %f | xT %i", hudX.progress, xP, xT);
     usleep(50000);
   }
}
```

The background process is (the xT variable is calculated here):

```
- (void) miniAutomatico                                {
    cwMonitorBz                                    = [[[CwMonitorBz alloc] init]autorelease];
    cwMonitorBz.persistentStoreCoordinator         = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    cwMonitorBz.managedObjectContextp              = self.managedObjectContextp;
    cwMonitorBz.gmCuenta                           = gmCuenta;
    cwMonitorBz.esCuentaCero                       = @"1";
    [self.cwMonitorBz monitorMinimoAuto];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"acabo..miniAutomatico");
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.splitViewController.view animated:YES];
    });
}
```

For some reason, hudX is not updated dynamically (real-time). It shows correct values: (int) XT from the background process, but lagged.  I guess that my main thread (UI) is blocked, but I don't know why or where.

How can I update my hudX on a real-tiem basis (UI)?.  Your response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/a/8709183/1262527

Comment: @ Mariam N. - (void) miniAutomatico triggers [self.cwMonitorBz monitorMinimoAuto]. in this method, I have two additional calls:- (void) calculoInteres:  and - (void) calculoMinimo: The last method (calculoMinimo) is called at the end of each loop.  Within this method I have  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        xyVueta ++;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:xyVueta forKey:kVueltas];
    }); which force to back to the main thread..something happens but not as faster to update hudX on a real-time basis..Do I missing something.

Comment: It looks like you're polling in `actEtiqueta`, which is an inherently inefficient process. Glancing at the source, it also looks like `showWhileExecuting` will fire off `actEtiqueta` in another thread, and I find UI updates in that other thread worrying (despite the author's assertions that you can update `detailsLabelText` and `progress` in the background). Whenever dealing with background operations, I'd rather see the background operation dispatch HUD updates to the main queue as it progresses, and avoid any polling mechanism at all.