# UIView setFrame thread safety

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiview

The UIView docs say "Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the main thread". Despite this, in my tests so far I have found that repositioning a view using setFrame from a background thread does work.

Can anyone confirm whether setFrame is thread safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All UI updating code ( including setFrame ) must be done on the main thread. I think you already know the answer to this :)

It may work in a background thread, but it doesn't mean it's **safe**.
To answer the question more directly, Apple pretty much says UIView code is not thread safe.

If you need to update the UI from a different thread, invoke it on the main thread using Grand Central Dispatch.

[Here's a kind of similar question @ stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682554/ui-changes-on-background-thread-due-to-nsuserdefaultsdidchangenotification)